# Select2: remove disabled attribute from submit button if all non-optional select boxes have selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 to style and add functionality to my select boxes. I want to force the users to move through the select dropdowns in order, so I start by disabling all select boxes and then enabling the first one. Each time the user makes a selection, the next select box becomes enabled. There will be a few selections that are optional so what I am trying to do is remove the `disabled` attribute from the submit button if all the non-optional selections have a value, but so far I have not been able to get it working correctly.

Here is my code so far:

```js
$(function() {
    $('select').select2({
        placeholder: '- Select -',
    });
    $('select').prop('disabled', true);
    $('select:first-of-type').prop('disabled', false);
    $('select').on('select2:select', function(e) {
        $(this).nextAll('select').first().prop('disabled', false);
        $(this).siblings('select').not('.optional').each(function () {
            //console.log($(this).val());
            if (!$(this).val()) {
                reqSelected = true;
            } else {
                reqSelected = false;
            }
        });
        console.log(reqSelected);
        if (reqSelected === true) {
            $(input).prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
label,select {
    display:block;
}

label {
    margin-top:20px;
}

label:first-child {
    margin-top:0;
}

input {
    display:block;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div clas="form">
  <label>1. Select Make</label>
  <select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
  </select>

  <label>2. Select Model</label>
  <select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
  </select>
  
  <label>3. Select Color (optional)</label>
  <select class="optional">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
  </select>
  
  <input type="submit" disabled />
</div>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muuarfy2/) if you want to play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try enabling the submit button itself with `$('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',false)`. You could use something like `$('select:last-of-type')` if only want to target it when the last dropdown is changed. You can also add any logic in there with `function()`

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate correct selections and when everything is OK then enable submit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var correctSelections = 0,
       requiredSelections = 3; //or whatever you need
   $('div.form')on('change', 'select', function(){
       if(/*this.is(':correctSelection')*/)
           correctSelections++;
       else
           correctSelections--;
       if(correctSelections == requiredSelections)
           $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',false);
  });
});
```